# How to enter and display German Umlauts on a Windows 10 machine with Russian locale?

Tags: microsoft-windows, unicode, keyboard-layout

I want to be able to write German texts using my Vim 7.4 installed on a Windows 10 machine with Russian locale and German keyboard layout.

My `.vimrc` file looks like this:

```
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
```

I can't neither enter German Umlauts, nor display those entered in another editor (i. e. `ä` is displayed like `a` etc.).

Russian text can be both entered and is displayed correctly.

How can I make sure that I can write in German, English and Russian in the Vim editor (in the same file) ?

Comment: What is the output of `:set termencoding`?

Comment: `termencoding=cp866`

Comment: I guess you can change it to `:set term encoding=utf8`

Comment: What line do I need to add to `.vimrc` in order for term encoding to *always* be UTF-8?

Comment: `:set termencoding=utf8` in vimrc

Answer (score 1):

After I reinstalled the program with "Native language support" disabled (in the installer), the problem disappeared.